# Laravel 5.8 get tables belonging to a user

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am listing all tables in the `DB`that are prefixed with the `user->id + _` (eg: `2_my_table`) like so:

```
$account = Auth()->user();
$tables = DB::select("SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . $account->id . "_%'");
```

This works and returns an array like this:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#577 ▼
    +"Tables_in_mydb (2_%)": "2_country_list"
  }
]
```

Why does it add the `(2_%)` search pattern to the `Tables_in_mydb` property?

This causes issues later when try and describe the tables like this:

```php
if (count($tables)) {
    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        $table->columns = DB::select('describe '.$table->Tables_in_mydb);
        $table->rows = DB::select('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM '.$table->Tables_in_mydb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed like this. But still do not understand the original issue.

```
$tables = collect(DB::select('show tables'))->filter(function ($val) use (&$account) {
    foreach ($val as $key => $tbl) {

        $tbl_prefix = $account->id . "_";
        $tbl_prefix_length = strlen($tbl_prefix);

       if (substr($tbl, 0, $tbl_prefix_length) == $tbl_prefix) {
            return $tbl;
       }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to go about it the long way.

By using `get_object_vars`, you can get the object values into an array. Then use array_values to get just the values:

```
 $table_name_arr = array_values(get_object_vars($table));
```

This will provide with an array `(0 => '2_country_list')`, which you can easily get with `$table_name_arr[0]`

For a one-liner, use

```
$table_name = array_values(get_object_vars($table))[0];
```